# invarient voilation: resources are not useable as native method argument

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am new here and stuck because of this error. please help me to solve this error.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
function ListItem({ image, title, subtitle }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {image && <Image style={styles.img} source={image} />}
        <View>
          <Text>{title}</Text>
          <Text>{subtitle}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  img: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 35
  }
});
export default ListItem;
```

and invoke it in other component with passing arguments

```
import * as React from "react";
import Icon from "./Components/Icon";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <ListItem
        title="My title"
        subtitle="subtitle"
        imgComponent={<Icon name="email" />}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

[and i am facing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnyAE.png)

Comment: You need to provide more context. The provided code snippets are not enough. Also provide a complete stacktrace of the error.

Comment: invarient voilation: [29, "RCTView",1,{"backgroundColor":-16777,"borderRadius":"<NaN>}] is not usable as a native method argument.                                                               This is the error showed on the emulator

Comment: when i remove the "imagecomponent" from listItem argument then it worked fine

Comment: Why is your borderRadius NaN?

Comment: Provide the entire code of this particular js file

Comment: i dont't have any idea. i think its just fake error. i have not used the borderRadius

Comment: function ListItem({ image, title, subtitle }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {image && <Image style={styles.img} source={image} />}
        <View>
          <Text>{title}</Text>
          <Text>{subtitle}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  img: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 35,
  },
  },
});
export default ListItem;

Comment: export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <ListItem title="My title" subtitle="subtitle" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    flex: 1,
  },
});

Comment: Edit your question. Add all the code with proper formatting. All the code - with imports etc. and complete stacktrace. The error you are receiving should mention a line where the error occurs. `{"backgroundColor":-16777,"borderRadius":"<NaN>}`where are you defining  a background and borderradius? Where is that code?

Comment: yes bro i have edit my question with necessary detail and also prove the link of image for error message

Comment: its error with your ```Icon ``` component as you showed the error,  add the code of Icon.js in the question as well